# Processing messages with PossDupFlag set with QuickFixJ

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

In QuickFix/J we can send a `ResendRequest` message to the Acceptor to request messages to be resent to the Initiator, within a given `MsgSeq` number range. For example:

```
Session session = Session.lookupSession(new SessionID("FIXT.1.1:SENDER->TARGET"));
session.send(new ResendRequest(new BeginSeqNo(1), new EndSeqNo(0)));
```

This message will request all existing Execution Reports for any open orders in the Acceptor.

The issue we have is that these messages come with `PossDupFlag` set to `Y` in the header. QuickFix/J by default ignores these messages and doesn't call the `fromApp` callback. I found that the callback *is* called if we set

```
ValidateSequenceNumbers=Y
```

but, as per the documentation, it has a drawback

> If not enabled and a mismatch is detected, nothing is done.

I was wondering:

- is there a different way for these messages to be processed by the callback?
- if there is no other way what are the consequences of setting `ValidateSequenceNumbers=Y`? Is it just detect the sequence number mismatch ourselves?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I found a solution for this problem. Basically, we need to tell QuickFix/J that our target `MsgSeqNum` is 1. The logic will detect that the actual target's `MsgSeqNum` is higher than the one we have set and it will send a `ResendRequest` to the Acceptor:

```
Session session = Session.lookupSession(new SessionID("FIXT.1.1:SENDER->TARGET"));
session.setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(1);
```

In this case, the `fromApp` callback **is** called even though the `PosDupFlag` is set in the messages.

Comment: Just wanted to tell you the same. There was a discussion recently here: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/discussions/483 Bottom line: don't interfere with session-level logic. ;)